# Is it possible to clear cache in iOS and Android webkit?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

The sdk I am using for my app calls up a webview that loads Facebook's login oauth login screen.  I can't find a way of logging the user out so that they can login as a different Facebook user as the view always loads with the credentials of the first user.  My only solution is to uninstall the app.

I have been using 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?method=delete&access_token=', which does in fact remove the user from my app, by I think the webkit cache keeps the last access_token around and just tries to reauthenticate it.

I haven't seen any apps so far that let you fully logout and login as a different user when using Facebook to authenticate.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this at time of logout

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *each in cookieStorage.cookies) {
        // put a check here to clear cookie url which starts with twitter and then delete it
        if ([[each valueForKey:@"domain"] isEqualToString:@".facebook.com"])
        { [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each]; }
        else
        {
            [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
        }

    }
```